# Postgres - Find records where LIKE and take MAX / UNION multiple

Tags: postgresql, select, max, union, sql-like

I have table where column has values:

```
'2017-12-1', '2017-12-5', '2017-12-15', '2015-12-1', '2016-12-25', '2012-12-18'
```

etc.

Now I want to select rows where column `LIKE '2017-12'` and union rows where column `LIKE '2015-12'`. So for `LIKE '2017-12'` I will get 3 records and for `LIKE '2015-12'` I will get 1 record. Now I want to UNION them but take only '2017-12-15' because it is MAX. I tried ORDER BY LIMIT 1 but it doesn't work with UNION.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, assuming the column stores dates as a character type.

```
SELECT x,MAX(CAST(substring(x from 9 for 10) AS integer)) AS m
FROM tmp1 WHERE substring(x from 1 for 7)='2015-12' OR substring(x from 1 for 7)='2017-12'
GROUP BY x ORDER BY x desc LIMIT 1
```

If you are storing a date type:

```
SELECT x FROM tmp WHERE to_char(x,'YYYY-MM')='2017-12' OR to_char(x,'YYYY-MM')='2015-12'
GROUP BY xORDER BY x desc LIMIT 1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you read my question? I need `UNION` of multiple `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ORDER BY column LIMIT 1` . Without `ORDER BY column LIMIT 1` the union of multiple selects works.